# 'No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.provider.DSAPublicKeyImpl' while using RSA encryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, keystore, dsa

I'm trying to encrypt a text file using a key I generated.
Now I should encrypt this key with RSA algorithm, using the public key of the side that eventually will receive the encrypted data.

This is my code so far:

```
package cryptogaphy;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;



public class trythree {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {

    // Generate a symmetric key
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    int keyBitSize = 128;
    keyGenerator.init(keyBitSize, secureRandom);
    SecretKey symmetricKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    Key key = symmetricKey;

    // Generate random IV
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    System.out.println("Random Iv: " + iv);

    // File Encryption
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Victoria\\Desktop\\plainData.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Victoria\\Desktop\\encryptedData.txt");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    write(cis, fos);


    // load Alice's keystore - input method should be changed
    char[] aliceStorePass = "123456".toCharArray();
    char[] aliceKeypass = "aliceKey".toCharArray();

    FileInputStream aliceInput = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Victoria\\Desktop\\aliceKeystore.jks");
    KeyStore aliceKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    aliceKeystore.load(aliceInput, aliceStorePass);

    String alias = "alice";
    String alias2 = "bobcert";

    Key aliceKey = aliceKeystore.getKey(alias, aliceKeypass);
    PublicKey bobPublicKey = null;

    // retrieve Alice's private key and Bob's public key from Alice's keystore
    if (aliceKey instanceof PrivateKey) {
      Certificate cert = aliceKeystore.getCertificate(alias2);
      bobPublicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
      new KeyPair(bobPublicKey, (PrivateKey) aliceKey);
      System.out.println((PrivateKey) aliceKey);
    }
    System.out.println("Bob's public key: " + bobPublicKey);

    // Encrypt the Symmetric Key with asymmetric RSA algorithm
    byte[] encryptedkey = symmetricKey.getEncoded();
    Cipher keyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
    keyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, bobPublicKey );  
    keyCipher.doFinal(encryptedkey);

    System.out.println("Asymmetric Secret Key: " + encryptedkey);
    System.out.println("Symmetric Key: " + key);



} catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException | CertificateException e){
System.out.println(e); 
}

    }



    private static void write(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[64];
        int numOfBytesRead;
        while((numOfBytesRead = in.read(buf))!=-1)
             {
                 out.write(buf, 0 ,numOfBytesRead);
             }     
           out.close();
           in.close();  
           System.out.println("-----ENCRYPTION COMPLETED!-----");
    }
}
```

Now, I get this error-

**java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.provider.DSAPublicKeyImpl**

The error mentions DSA, although I used RSA.
Any ideas how to solve it? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems bobPublicKey is a DSA key and DSA can not be used for encryption, only for digital signatures.

`Cipher` init fails because RSA encryption can not be performed with a DSA key (The error message says that no cryptographic provider supports it)

```
Cipher keyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
keyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, bobPublicKey );
```

See [What is the difference between DSA and RSA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841094/what-is-the-difference-between-dsa-and-rsa)

Comment: Could you post a sample key or the keytool commands you have used? Note that "DSA" is the default option for `-genkeypair`

Comment: There is a command that prints out the certificate information somewhere in `openssl`, no doubt using the `openssl x509` command. That should list the algorithm of the public key inside.